# Add Buttons to Delete Posts PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, database

I'm trying to add buttons to delete posts.

If I press the button to delete the post, the page reloads but the post is not deleted.

Furthermore, the POST_ID of the post is not taken.

I don't know how to make it right.

Help me please.

```html
<?php
                 
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_email'])){
                
          global $con;
          global $u_id;
          
          if (isset($_GET['u_id'])) {
              $u_id = $_GET['u_id'];
          }
          
          $get_posts = "select * from posts where user_id='$u_id' ORDER by 1 DESC LIMIT 5"; 
          
          $run_posts = mysqli_query($con, $get_posts); 
          
          while ($row_posts = mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)) { 
              
          }
            
            
           $coin_id = $row_posts['coin_id'];
           $user_id = $row_posts['user_id'];
              
              
            
            
        foreach($infos as $inf) {
                echo
                
               '<div class="container">'.
                
                '<div class="col-sm-7 border rounded mx-left" style="height: 50px; display: inline-block;">' . $inf['user_crypto'] . ',' . $inf['user_code'] . '</div>' . 
                

                '<a href="functions/delete_coin.php?coin_id='.$coin_id.'" name="delete_coin" style="float:right;"><button class="btn btn-info">' . 'X' . '</button>' . '</a>' .
                
                '</div>' .
                
                '<br>';
        
            }

          }
          
            include("functions/delete_coin.php");
          
        ?>
```

And then This is the Php file with the function DELETE:

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","coin") or die("Connection was not established");



if(isset($_GET['coin_id'])){
    $coin_id = $_GET['coin_id'];
    
    $delete_coin = "delete from posts where coin_id='$coin_id'";
    
    $run_delete = mysqli_query($con, $delete_coin);
    
    if($run_delete){
        echo "<script>alert('A Post have been deleted!')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('../start.php', '_self')</script>";
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Side note: Running a delete on a GET request isn't advised.

Comment: Side note: You are open to SQL injection attacks.  Use prepared queries.

Comment: What is `ORDER BY 1` in your SQL?  I thought column names could not be entirely digits?  Correction, you can use them, but it isn't recommended.

Comment: What do you mean by: `the POST_ID of the post is not taken`?

Comment: Is the `coin_id` GET variable correct?

Comment: @Progrock Yeah, I'm sure it isn't deleted.

Comment: @Progrock Ok, I'll delete GET and what is best to use for my project? (I'm a beginner with Php)

Comment: @Progrock "ORDER BY 1" is a piece of old code. I'll delete it

Comment: @PeterSH I don't know. In this case I'm not sure of anything.

Comment: @Progrock "localhost/....delete_coin.php?coin_id= "  The post (which I would like to delete) and its ID are not selected.